# How to retrieve beans using two relations on redbean

Tags: redbean

I would like to retrieve some data using one-to-many and many-to-many relations
I've created bean called floor, shop, category and related them as:

```
floor 1:N shop
floor N:M category
shop N:M category
```

Now i want to retrive all shops given category and floor ids
Here is my code

```
$floor = R::load('floor',$f_id);
$category = R::load('category',$cat_id);
$shops= $floor->via('category')->withCondition('id = ?',[$category ->id])->ownShopList;
var_dump($shops);
```

But $data is empty array. I'm shure i've related beans correctly. What am I doing wrong please help!
Maybe there is another way to retrieve them i'll appreciate any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$category = R::load('category',$cat_id);
$shops= $category->withCondition('floor_id = ?',[$f_id])
                 ->sharedShopList;
```

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out finally after couple of hours was very easy and simple. so here is the solution

```
$category = R::load('category',$cat_id);
$shops= $category->withCondition('floor_id = ?',[$f_id])->sharedShopList;
var_dump($shops);
```